# Help loading textures in PVRTC format for the iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm programming a small app with opengl for the iphone, and now I want to load textures in the PVRTC format. Is this complicated ?. Right now all my textures are in .png format, and I'm using this method for loading them:

```
- (void)loadTexture:(NSString*)nombre {

    CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:nombre].CGImage;
    if (textureImage == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load texture image");
        return;
    }

    textureWidth = NextPowerOfTwo(CGImageGetWidth(textureImage));   
    textureHeight = NextPowerOfTwo(CGImageGetHeight(textureImage));

    imageSizeX= CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
    imageSizeY= CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)calloc(1,textureWidth * textureHeight * 4); 

    CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, textureWidth,textureHeight,8, textureWidth * 4,CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );
    CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)textureWidth, (float)textureHeight), textureImage);

    CGContextRelease(textureContext);
    a
    glGenTextures(1, &textures[0]);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);


    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    free(textureData);


    glEnable(GL_BLEND);


    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   

}
```

Modifying this function to read PVRTC is complicated ?, how can I do it ?

Comment: Not that it's got anything to do with your question, but you're not releasing the initial UIImage object. Before you get it's CGImage property, assign it to an id variable and release it after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you'll want to look at the PVRTextureLoader sample.  It's a very simple file format.  The key piece is the header structure:

```
typedef struct _PVRTexHeader
{
    uint32_t headerLength;
    uint32_t height;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t numMipmaps;
    uint32_t flags;
    uint32_t dataLength;
    uint32_t bpp;
    uint32_t bitmaskRed;
    uint32_t bitmaskGreen;
    uint32_t bitmaskBlue;
    uint32_t bitmaskAlpha;
    uint32_t pvrTag;
    uint32_t numSurfs;
} PVRTexHeader;
```

You can then slurp the entire file with **dataWithContentsOfFile**, and simply cast the result to the structure:

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString* fullPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:nombre];
NSData* fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
PVRTexHeader* header = (PVRTexHeader*) [fileData bytes];
char* imageData = (char*) [fileData bytes] + header->headerLength;
```

To determine the texture format, you can look at the **flags** field in the struct.  Don't forget to call **glCompressedTexImage2D** rather than **glTexImage2D**.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PVRTextureLoader example in the developer documentation in XCode. It has all you need.